# How close can an output transformer be to a preamp tube?

Tags: amplifier, noise, vacuum-tube

Imagine a layout for a tube amplifier. The power transformer is on one side, and the output transformer, input jack, and preamp tubes are on the other side. (Take a look at the Soldano SLO for example)

Guitar amps have a huge amount of gain, and the layout is crucial to prevent parasitic oscillations, etc, but I've never seen this question answered.

Exactly how close can the output transformer be to the preamp tubes? Is it better if the end bells are facing the preamp tubes or if the laminations are?

I'm sure it depends on the gain of the amp of course.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Close as you want: use mu-metal or other shield on the preamp and/or xfmr

Comment: Full metal jackets were quite common on vacuum tubes.

Comment: Closer is better to avoid parasitics? Forgive my lack of understanding, I was assuming that if the transformer is too close to a preamp tube, the magnetic field from the transformer would induce a signal in the tube, which would then create feedback, possibly not even at audio frequencies, ie, parasitic oscillations. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @catpants Oscillation yes, but not one caused by parasitics. Parasitics means something pretty specific. Maybe we have different words for the same thing.

Comment: Okay, parasitic oscillation seems to mean any undesired oscillation, not just one caused by parasitics.